# Adobe Indesign is not applying styles to imported XML

Tags: xml, text, adobe-indesign

I want to import text into InDesign from an XML file and automatically apply a style to that tag. I already have made a style for every XML tag in the document. However when I drag the text into a frame the style isn't applied. I do see colored tags around the text so I think InDesign knows which style it should apply but just doesn't show it. Is there maybe some setting to enable this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: how are you applying your styles? Are you using grep styles?

Comment: after testing it locally, I can achieve what you want using a combination of 1 Paragraph style and multiple character styles. Each character style is the style of a tag. The paragraph style uses each character style as grep styles. My only problem so far is I need to apply the paragraph style to the imported text every time I import new text, as if the imported text does not inherit the style already applied in the textbox. FYI, a grep style uses a regular expressions to qualify portions of the text that need to be applied the given character style.

Comment: Not using grep styles. I fixed it by correctly introducing newlines in the xml document. It works when you give every tag and content it's own line.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map tags to styles:

[image]

Then we you place xml into the layout the nodes content should be styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of XML structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"><p aid:pstyle="Paragraph Style 1">Hi, This is first paragraph with applied paragraph style ==Paragraph Style 1</p>&#x2029;<p aid:pstyle="Paragraph Style 2">Hi, This is first paragraph with applied paragraph style ==Paragraph Style 2</p>&#x2029;<p aid:pstyle="Paragraph Style 3">Hi, This is first paragraph with applied paragraph style <span aid:cstyle="Bold">==Paragraph Style 3==</span>, this name is also applied with character style Bold</p>&#x2029;<p aid:pstyle="Paragraph Style 3"><span aid:cstyle="Bold">Bold character Style</span>&#x2028;<span aid:cstyle="Italic">Italic character Style</span>&#x2028;<span aid:cstyle="BoldItalic">BoldItalic character Style</span>&#x2028;All character styles are separated by Soft return Entity i.e &amp;#x2028; and paragraphs are separated with Paragraph end entity i.e. &amp;#x2029;</p></root>
```